# How to make emacs show correct hex color on background?

Tags: terminal-emacs, colors

The way I run `emacs`:

`TERM=xterm-256color emacs -nw <my_file>`

---

I am trying to have background on `dracula-theme` (https://github.com/dracula/dracula-theme).

[image]

---

I have added following line into `.emacs`:

`(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "#282a36"))`

Expected color:

[image]

but some blue color show up instead:

[image]

---

I have also installed the draculate them but similiar problem occurs.

(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")
(load-theme 'dracula t)

Possible bug: https://github.com/dracula/emacs/issues/32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you applied a theme? In which case

M-x: describe-face

type "default"

See what that is.

Also, remember that terminals have pallettes. This [stack exchange article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950/how-to-make-emacs-terminal-colors-the-same-as-emacs-gui-colors) will get you going.

Comment: I have applied the theme as `(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes");
(load-theme 'dracula t)`  // when I type default I get `Background: #000000`